# Matlab cell to array not working

Tags: matlab

I have this cell (16x1) in MATLAB:

```
eventIDs = 

    'explosion'
    'light'
    'darkness'
    'atomic'
    ...
    ..
```

now I want to use this :

```
%First bar plotting!
bar(duration_vector);
d = size(duration_vector);
labels = cell2mat(eventIDs);
xticklabel_rotate([1:d],45,eventIDs,'interpreter','none');
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:d, 'XTickLabel', labels);
```

I want to plot a bar graph but my events I too long, and I want them rotated to look good!

but when I run the code 
I get this:

```
??? Error using ==> cat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> cell2mat at 85
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Error in ==> extract_data at 52
labels = cell2mat(eventIDs);
```

Answer (score 2):

cell2mat in Matlab only works if your cell has a consistent number of columns in all rows. That is so because Matlab can't handle normal arrays with a variable number of columns per row, and that's generally the case of string matrices.
That said, cell manipulations is almost equal to matrix manipulation, the only difference being the indexation method: matrices use square brackets ([) and cells use curly brackets.

I googled the code of this function you're using, the xticklabel_rotate, and found the fileexchange link to the function [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486). There, the example given by the author uses a cell, instead of a matrix.

So I'm guessing that you can drop this `cell2mat` off because I thik you don't need to set the Xticks with the `set` function you're using. The `xticklabel_rotate` should do that.

I think you should try this:

```
%First bar plotting!
bar(duration_vector);
d = size(duration_vector);
xticklabel_rotate([1:d],45,eventIDs,'interpreter','none');
```

Comment: I forgot to delete the two lines I would delete :p, basically just drop the set and the cell2mat and it should work

Comment: sorry I am getting this:
??? Undefined function or method 'xticklabel_rotate' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> extract_data at 53
xticklabel_rotate([1:d],45,eventIDs,'interpreter','none');

Comment: enter the link I posted on the answer, download the code there, put it on your working directory and give it a try (if it complains about the function not being defined for input arguments of type cell

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `cell2mat`. That tries to create a 2D matrix of characters (which fails because your strings are different lengths).

You also don't need the `set(...` line because `xticklabel_rotate` already sets the labels.

Comment: I get this:
??? Undefined function or method 'xticklabel_rotate' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> extract_data at 53
xticklabel_rotate([1:d],45,eventIDs,'interpreter','none');

Comment: The `xticklabel_rotate.m` file needs to be in your Matlab search path. (Easiest is to put it in the dir your working in, or add its location to the path.)